# How to fetch() from public folder in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, web-worker

I've got following use case scenario. I have web worker within which I need to fetch image that is located in NextJS `public` folder in order to convert it to blob.

Right now executing `fetch('public/images/myImage.png');` or `fetch('/images/myImage.png');` leads to an error:

> Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope':
>   Failed to parse URL from /images/ui/background_fire.jpg

So I assume it is not being resolved correctly like it would in say `src` of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **[official Docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows)** you need to use [isomorphic-unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch).

`It's a simple implementation of the browser fetch API, but works both in client and server environments.`

Install it

$`npm install --save isomorphic-unfetch`

or

$`yarn add isomorphic-unfetch`

Now you can use it in from `getInitialProps` to any where in your component.

Example ::

```
`import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';`

// ... Index component code

Index.getInitialProps = async function() { 

  const res = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman');
  const data = await res.json();
    
  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`);
    
  return {
    shows: data.map(entry => entry.show)
  };
};
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 3):

@NasiruddinSaiyed answer is a bit outdated so here is the 2021 answer:

[NextJS server-side-polyfills docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#server-side-polyfills)

> #### Server-Side Polyfills
>
> In addition to fetch() on the client side, Next.js polyfills fetch() in the Node.js environment. You can use fetch() on your server code (such as getStaticProps) without using polyfills such as isomorphic-unfetch or node-fetch.

So it should just work out of the box